# Click event on td not firing

Tags: jquery, html-table, onclick

I'm generating the table in PHP and adding it to HTML using
I add PHP code to HTML in this way:

```
$('#pnametable').html(myVar);
```

my PHP Code:

```
$str="<table id='notable'>";    
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){       
   $str.="<tr id='gtpname'><td class='pnotd'>".$row['pname']."</td></tr>";       
}       
$str.="</table>";`
```

Now my jQuery code goes like this:

```
$("#notable > tbody > tr > td").click(function() {       
  alert("wdwad");      
});
```

Please help me find solutions for it.

Comment: Have you tried using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: You did not add a `tbody` tag in your code, are you certain the browser will add one for you?

Comment: Duplicate of maybe a million other questions. `.click` only works on elements that already exist in the DOM at the time your code executes. If you're adding elements later, you need to use `on`.

Comment: yaa..using firebug i saw browser adding it..

Comment: Did you remember to wrap your code in `document.ready`, and are you fetching the HTML with ajax ?

Comment: see i would not mind if any1 of you can solve it using teamviewr as i m geting mad with it from 1hr..

Comment: guys it worked with live()..should i continue using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data which is generated is dynamic.  Try using "on" method.

Comment: I think td is added dynamically by javascript.. so at that point document doesn't have td.

Comment: I think what you are doing is you are generating HTML in back end and passing that to myvar variable.. so at that point document is loaded and it doesn't have td.

Comment: yaaa..so now how to i get that td

Comment: The way you are doing is fine

Comment: But instead of click method, use on method which is similar to live method.  But don't use live method.

Comment: $('#pnametable').on('click','#notable td', function(){
    alert("wdwad");
});

Comment: Try this: $(document).on('click','#notable td', function(){ alert("wdwad"); });​

Comment: dude now how do i get the value of a particular clicked td..i tried this      `var pnoname = $('#notable td').html();` but it gives me only of 1st td in table.

Comment: So when you click the td, get that object by $(this) once you get that object, you can use .text() - to get text inside that div.

Comment: i got a problem here see my project is using jquery calendar..so if use this **jquery.min.js version  v1.3.2** your .on method doest not work,even though i m decalring jquery v1.7.2 before this.

Comment: if you use jquery version before 1.7.2, live method is what you can use. But if you use jquery version more than 1.7+, "on" method will work..

Comment: for live : $('#notable td').live('click',function(){}); 
Note : "live" is deprecated after 1.7 jquery version.

Comment: k..thnx dude..bt can what should i do now..because my calendar is asking for **1.3.2** and .on method wants **1.7.2**

Comment: I wont recommend using the load jquery version, because there are lots of new methods added after that.  But still if you want to use the calendar plugin, go with the old one.

Comment: dude can u come n see my prject jst once..as wer am i getng wrong..becoz it need v1.3.2 only for resize and drop in calendar.

Comment: which plugin is that ? is it possible to use any other plugin ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not 100% clear how are you building your table, but it seems you're doing it dynamically. If this is the case, you need to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method like this

```
$('#pnametable').on('click','#notable td', function(){
    alert("wdwad");
});
```

I'm assuming that this client code is building the table

```
$('#pnametable').html(myVar);
```

Comment: yaa..i m echoing from php the tbale and myvar varibale gets it.

Comment: dude i tried this .on() bt it did not work.. in fact it did not allow my JQUERY calender dialog box to load.

Comment: @Kaushil Rambhia: could you tell me if there is any js error on your page? (use firebug or any other developer tools)

Comment: dude if u cn plz come through team viewer

Comment: which jquery version are you using?

Comment: @Kaushil Rambhia: please paste your code on the question, I'd like to see what's the difference. `on` should work and `live` is deprecated and not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery selector is off.  It is looking for a tbody, but your PHP code doesn't create a tbody.

You can either modify the PHP like this:

```
$str="<table id='notable'><tbody>";    
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){       
   $str.="<tr id='gtpname'><td class='pnotd'>".$row['pname']."</td></tr>";       
}       
$str.="</tbody></table>";
```

Or change the jquery selector to this:
`$("#notable > tr > td")`